# Shell Script: Copy first file from multiple folders into one single folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-copy

In a directory, I have hundreds of sub-directories.  Each sub-directory has hundreds of jpg pictures.  If the folder is called "ABC_DEF", the files inside the folder will be called "ABC_DEF-001.jpg", "ABC_DEF-002.jpg", so on and so forth.

For example:

```
---Main Directory
------Sub-Directory ABC_DEF
----------ABC_DEF-001.jpg
----------ABC_DEF-002.jpg
------Sub-Directory ABC_GHI
----------ABC_GHI-001.jpg
----------ABC_GHI-002.jpg
```

From each of the sub-directory I want to copy only the first file, e.g., the file with the extension -001.jpg - to a common destination folder called DESTDIR.

I have changed the code given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241494/bash-command-to-get-first-and-last-file-from-each-folder-recursive) to suit my use case.  However, it always prints the first directory along with the filenames and I am not able to copy the files to the desired destination.  The following is the code:

```
DIR=/var/www/html/beeinfo.org/resources/videos/
find "$DIR" -type d |
while read d;
do
    files=$(ls -t "$d" | sed -n '1h; $ { s/\n/,/g; p }')
    printf '%s,%s\n' "$files";
done
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: The other question had a more difficult task because they didn't know anything about the name of the first file and needed to combine it with the last file. Unfortunally the answer didn't explain the `sed` script, so you didn't know how to adapt it. Your case it much simpler and you don't need that stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why `find` when all files are in directories of the same depth?

```
cd -- "$DIR" &&
  cp -- */*-001.jpg /destination/path
```

Comment: This makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @igal - beware of [the limitations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110282) of this solution though... Per OP, that glob will expand to only some hundreds of file names but still, it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Philippos Many thanks...this is quite intuitive and help me straight away.

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do with `find` only if you supposed to pick the first file which is ending with `-001.jpg` pattern and only one in each sub-directory, so the command would be:

```
find . -name "*-001.jpg" -execdir echo cp -v {} /path/to/dest/ \;
```

**Note**: remove the `echo` for dry run once the result was what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find -exec {} +` to get a list of the files and call `cp` just once:

```
find /path/to/main/dir -name "*-001.jpg" -exec cp -t /path/to/dest/dir/ {} +
```

To test what it does first, replace `cp` with `echo cp`.

Comment: [same for `-exec` with `+` terminator as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403486/shell-script-copy-first-file-from-multiple-folders-into-one-single-folder/403491#comment721415_403501)

Answer (score 0):

For the first regular file in numeric order of each sub directory, with `zsh`, you could do:

```
cp -- *(/e['reply=($REPLY/*(Nn.[1]))']) /path/to/destination/
```

For the oldest:

```
cp -- *(/e['reply=($REPLY/*(NOm.[1]))']) /path/to/destination/
```